# Angular @ContentChildren QueryList does not detect changes when TemplateRef is passed in via @Input

Tags: angular, templates, angular2-template

I'll start with my component's usage on a hosting component:

```html
<my-templated-component [content-template]="contentTemplate">
</my-templated-component>

<ng-template #contentTemplate>
  <h3>Hello There</h3>
  <div>Lorem ipsum..... </div>
  <custom-component></custom-component>
</ng-template>
```

Now, my component's .ts:

```
class MyTemplatedComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  @Input('content-template') contentTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ContentChildren(CustomComponent) customComponentQueryList: QueryList<CustomComponent>;

  ...
  ngAfterContentInit() {

    // Length is 0 at this point. My component didn't find the component I want
    console.log(`There are ${this.customComponentQueryList.length} items`);

    this.customComponentQueryList.changes.subscribe((s) => {
      /* This is not called. This is where I would have wanted to find
         my CustomComponent to perform a task that requires its presence.
      */
    });
  }
}
```

And here is the markup for `MyTemplatedComponent`:

```html
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="contentTemplate">
</ng-container>
```

I understand that the `QueryList<CustomComponent>` will only be available at `ngAfterContentInit()`. Without subscribing to it, `CustomComponentQueryList` has zero items, so it hasn't found a `CustomComponent` from the `@Input`ted `TemplateRef`. But the `changes` of the `QueryList<CustomComponent>` isn't triggered, so I definitely can't find my component.

The strange thing is that I see everything from that `@Input`ted `TemplateRef` on the page, *including* the markup from `CustomComponent`. So, `MyTemplatedComponent` *does* detect my inputted template ref and displays it through `*ngTemplateOutlet`, but the `QueryList` can't find my `CustomComponent`?

---

Now, however, if I changed `@Input() contentTemplate: TemplateRef<any>` to
`@ContentChild('contentTemplate') contentTemplate: TemplateRef<any>`, and then put the template *inside* the tags of `<my-templated-component>` like this:

```html
<my-templated-component>
  <ng-template #contentTemplate>
    <h3>Hello There</h3>
    <div>Lorem ipsum..... </div>
    <custom-component></custom-component>   
  </ng-template>
</my-templated-component>
```

The `QueryList` `changes` *does* get triggered, and from the subscription, I can find my `CustomComponent`.

Perhaps `@ContentChild` and `@ContentChildren` will only work *if and only if* I straight-up put the `<ng-template>` as an immediate element child of my component's markup/selector as I've done above.

But I won't always get to plop `<my-templated-component>` this way, and there will be times where the `<ng-template #contentTemplate>` might even come from outside the hosting component.

Everything is fine if all I want to do is to take in `TemplateRefs` and display them somewhere in my templated components, but I'll need to investigate the *contents* of the `TemplateRefs` I'll receive for various purposes.

If `@ContentChildren` requires that I put my `<ng-template>`s inside my component's tags, what would be the equivalent decorator (I don't think there is one, and it's definitely not `@ViewChildren`), if the `TemplateRef` was passed via `@Input`? Any effective workarounds?

Ultimately, from inside templated components, how do we find certain components inside `TemplateRef`s passed in as `@Input` if `@ContentChildren` `QueryList<T>` don't work?

Comment: hmmm..just ran into this issue ... I know the OP is old...but did you ever solve?